# question about proofs and logic

Tags: probability, statistics

so i got this question in a seminar of mine in a course about advanced algorithms:

Your company owns a data center of n>1,000 computers. You learned that
some of these computers may be infected by a virus. Due to the security
setup, this infection will not affect your data center if less than 10% of the
computers got infected.
Since checking for an infection is expensive, your boss wants to perform the
check only on a (uniformly random) sample of 10 computers. Your boss
claims that if at least 10% of the computers got infected, then with
probability at least 9/10, at least one of the sampled computers is infected.

At the beggining i was thinking that the assumptions are correct (i dont know if th assumption of the manager that the probability is at least 9/10) but i am generally stuck.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

thanks in advance!

Comment: To be clear, the question here is "is your boss correct", right?

Comment: @79037662 yess prove or disprove him

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, suppose exactly 10% of the computers are infected.

Now, let $n$ be the total number of computers (of which $\frac{n}{10}$ are infected). The chance that none of the computers in your sample of $10$ will be
$$\frac{9n/10}{n}\cdot\frac{9n/10}{n-1}\cdots\frac{9n/10}{n-9}$$

Since $n$ is much larger than $10$ we can approximate this value with $\left(\frac{9n/10}{n}\right)^{10}=\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^{10}\approx0.349$. Remember, this is the probability that none of the computers are infected, so the probability that at least one is infected will be approximately $1-0.349=0.651<0.9$ so your boss is incorrect.

Comment: I think you may add something to deal with the "uniformly at random" since the procedure to pick the samples you answer suggest is to pick them one by one. In other words, order matters. But in the question, order does not matter. I would expect a sum of more complicated binomial coefficient to appear.

Comment: @Quentin I'm not sure what you mean, where in my answer did I suggest order matters?

Comment: In saying that the probability is $(9n/10)/n\cdots$. This means that you first consider one uniformly at random then take a second uniformly at random in the remaining computer and so on. You may consider all the computer at one I  think.

Comment: Considering choosing things one at a time is exactly how the binomial formula was derived in the first place! Say you have 5 items and want to choose 3 of them. The number of ways of doing so is $5\cdot4\cdot3/3!$ because there are 5 choices for your first thing, 4 for your second, and 3 for your third, then 3! ways to permute those items.

Comment: Yes of course. That's something like that I suggested to add. I mean I don't think it should be considered as trivial for such a question.

Comment: I don't think it's relevant to this answer, though. The difference between probability of your first computer being infected and your 10th computer being infected in negligible because $n$ is so much larger than $10$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: suppose $10\%$ are infected and you sample $10$ computers with replacement, i.e. each computer independently has probability $1/10$ of being infected. What is the probability of none of the sample being infected?

As $n$ tends to infinity, the chance of picking the same computer more than once tneds to zero, which means the probability for sampling without replacement tends to the value you just calculated.